# Can I import a list of modules from a shared file? i.e. can I import imports?

Tags: python, web-scraping, import, module

I have about a dozen python module imports that are going to be reused on many different scrapers, and I would love to just throw them into a single file (scraper_functions.py) that also contains a bunch of functions, like this:

```
import smtplib
import requests
import re
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

def function_name(var1)
    # function code here
```

then in my scraper I would simply do something like:

```
import scraper_functions
```

and be done with it. But listing the imports at the top of scraper_functions.py doesn't work, and neither does putting all the imports in a function. In each case I get errors in the scraper that is doing the importing.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "{actual-scraper-name-here}.py", line 24, in <module>
    x = requests.get(main_url)
NameError: name 'requests' is not defined
```

In addition, in VSCode, under Problems, I get errors like

```
Undefined variable 'requests' pylint(undefined-variable) [24,5]
```

None of the modules are recognized. I have made sure that all files are in the same directory.

Is such a thing possible please?

Comment: Please post your code **and** tracebacks (error messages) to help us reproduce your problem and better understand what is wrong

Comment: It would be helpful to see what error messages are being issued, if you could post these?

Comment: I ran this with no errors, could you perhaps add your errors to the question as I see no problem with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either use the `scraper_functions` prefix (same way you do this import name) or use the `from` keyword to import your things from `scraper_functions` with the `*` selector.

Using the `form` keyword (Recommended)

```py
from scraper_functions import * # import everything with *

...

x = requests.get(main_url)
```

Using the `scraper_functions` prefix (Not recommended)

```py
import scraper_functions

...

x = scraper_functions.requests.get(main_url)
```